# android where System.loadLibrary loads files

Tags: android

Some articles on the web tell me that `System.loadLibrary()` will load files in `/data/data/{app package}` directory. I wonder if this varies on each vendor implementation or fixed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is ultimately up to the vendor to define the filesystem / filesystem layout. So it might be in a different place. If there is no customized definition then the libraries will be in `/data/data/your.package.name/lib`.

In case it is in a different directory then `System.loadLibrary` will know that and load the library from that place.

Comment: So does it mean System.loadLibrary guarantee to check files in /data/data/your.package.name/lib ?

Comment: `System.loadLibrary("mylibrary")` will try load that library from the correct path whereever it is on the device. It is very likely `/data/data/your.package.name/lib/mylibrary.so`

Comment: @zapl right, except that the library filename `System.loadLibrary()` loads begins with "lib": ...`lib/libmylibrary.co`

Answer (score 0):

Better/newer answer: You can get the library directory with:

getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir

That /data/data/your.package.name/lib used to be the right place, but for some reasons, this isn't consistently everywhere the case.