# Which method eventually calls JNI_OnLoad

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I was trying to figure out how JNI_OnLoad is called internally. I eventually figured out the below tutorial but it does not throw any light on what code part actually calls JNI_OnLoad as an internal function call. Please help me with finding that link function which explicitly calls JNI_OnLoad. i observed that System.loadLibrary calls Runtime which again calls Classloader. But still could not find the native link.

I was especially interested with the one in OnLoad.cpp (android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/jni/onload.cpp)

```
JNI_OnLoad

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved);

The VM calls JNI_OnLoad when the native library is loaded (for example, through 
System.loadLibrary). JNI_OnLoad must return the JNI version needed by the native library.
In order to use any of the new JNI functions, a native library must export a JNI_OnLoad function that returns JNI_VERSION_1_2. If the native library does not export a JNI_OnLoad function, the VM assumes that the library only requires JNI version JNI_VERSION_1_1. If the VM does not recognize the version number returned by JNI_OnLoad, the native library cannot be loaded.
```

**Edit**: My file trace based on  response of @Code Painters is below:

```
       System.loadLibrary("android_servers");
            |
            |The call System.loadLibrary(name) is effectively equivalent
            |  to the call
            |
            V
        Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary(name)
            |
            |public static Runtime getRuntime() {
            |        return currentRuntime;}
            |
            | // Here, also,Classloader.loadlibrary is called, 
            | but this is over-ridden (?)
            | by the Native function of Runtime.java below
            V
        /dalvik/vm/native/java_lang_Runtime.cpp (The jni native
        implementation of Runtime.java):
        /*
         * static String nativeLoad(String filename, ClassLoader loader)
         *
         * Load the specified full path as a dynamic library filled with
         * JNI-compatible methods. Returns null on success, or a failure
         * message on failure.
         */
        static void Dalvik_java_lang_Runtime_nativeLoad{
        //
        success = dvmLoadNativeCode(fileName, classLoader, &reason);
        }
```

I now understand **Runtime.loadlibrary is overloaded with the Dalvik_java_lang_Runtime_nativeLoad native function** and Classloader.loadlibrary is not evoked. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the question is. Are you looking for the place in the source code where call to JNI_OnLoad() is done? In what VM implementation?

Comment: Yes. I am getting lost eventually when I dig deep to find the same...
Especially in the Android scenario.

Comment: [android where System.loadLibrary loads files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861372/android-where-system-loadlibrary-loads-files)

Comment: I've updated my answer - does it address your needs now?

Comment: I would not call it **overloading** - `Runtime.loadLibrary()` delegates the call to `private static native boolean nativeLoad(String filename, ClassLoader loader);`, which is declared native, as every native method it's implemented in C or C++. Tthat's how JNI works - you declare (and only declare) a method in Java with `native` keyword, and implement it in C/C++.

Comment: Beside that, the chain of calls you list looks correct. Also, there's no such thing as `ClassLoader.loadLibrary()` - there are `loadLibraryWithClassLoader()` and `loadLibraryWithPath()` methods, but as far as I can see both are empty in `ClassLoader`, and no `ClassLoader` subclass ever implements them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Android, you should look into [dalvik/vm/Native.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/eclair-release/vm/Native.c), which defines the JNI interface.

The most relevant function is this one:

```
bool dvmLoadNativeCode(const char* pathName, Object* classLoader);
```

This the place, where the library is `dlopen()`-ed. And the most interesting part of it:

```
    vonLoad = dlsym(handle, "JNI_OnLoad");
    if (vonLoad == NULL) {
        LOGD("No JNI_OnLoad found in %s %p\n", pathName, classLoader);
    } else {
        /*
         * Call JNI_OnLoad.  We have to override the current class
         * loader, which will always be "null" since the stuff at the
         * top of the stack is around Runtime.loadLibrary().  (See
         * the comments in the JNI FindClass function.)
         */
        OnLoadFunc func = vonLoad;
        Object* prevOverride = self->classLoaderOverride;

        self->classLoaderOverride = classLoader;
        oldStatus = dvmChangeStatus(self, THREAD_NATIVE);
        LOGV("+++ calling JNI_OnLoad(%s)\n", pathName);
        version = (*func)(gDvm.vmList, NULL);
        dvmChangeStatus(self, oldStatus);
        self->classLoaderOverride = prevOverride;
```

As you can see, `JNI_OnLoad` is simply resolved using `dlsym()` and called using the returned pointer. The rest of this code part is checking the value returned by `JNI_OnLoad`, nothing really exciting.

I believe it should look pretty much the same for other VMs - so just grep for `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` - after all it's just plain shared library loading and symbol resolution.

**Edit:** Speaking of the exact file you mention, `Android.mk` in the same directory compiles and links this file into `libandroid_servers` shared library. Grepping around for this library name reveals [services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java).

What's relevant:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    System.loadLibrary("android_servers");
    // ...
}
```

So, the loading of library (and thus a call to `JNI_OnLoad()` in `onload.cpp`) is performed in the context of Android's *system service* startup. If you want to know more about how/when the system service loads, I recommend [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/opersys/understanding-the-android-system-server).

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to know its implementation relation with System.loadLibrary specifically. As I have mentioned, the JNI_load that I am referreng to is in OnLoad.cpp(linked in the question)

Comment: But this is exactly what I've pointed you to. System.loadLibrary() is implemented in C, and the part of it cited above is responsible for calling JNI_OnLoad when the library is load. Your question was a bit confusing - you asked for "function which explicitly calls JNI_OnLoad".

Comment: The first link is dead.